# Using multiple rewrite rules in apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to get apache to rewrite some url's and I can get individual conditions to work but I can't get them to work together. The first thing I am doing is redirecting non secure requests to secure requests and at the same time removing a preceding "www" using the following lines.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.ourdomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://ourdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This is working fine.

I also have a subfolder with it's own .htaccess to do some tidy search engine friendly rewriting. so the folder `/subfolder` has its own .htaccess containing

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\-\.]+) /subfolder.cfm?slug=$1 [QSA]
```

and this is also working. However I want this folder rule to be in the root .htaccess so the folder can be deleted using something more like this.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.ourdomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://ourdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule /subfolder/([A-Za-z0-9\-\.]+) /subfolder.cfm?slug=$1 [QSA]
```

Unfortunately no matter what I try I can't get it to work, this is clearly a simple issue and my inability to fix it is making me pull what little hair I have left, clean out!

Comment: When rewriting is configured in .htaccess, the URL path the rules match against _never_ starts with a slash, that has been stripped off at this point already. So remove the leading slash; or better yet, replace it with a `^` , if you don’t want this to match `subfolder` just _anywhere_ in the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When rewriting is configured in .htaccess, the URL path the rules match against never starts with a slash, that has been stripped off at this point already. So remove the leading slash; or better yet, replace it with a ^ , if you don’t want this to match subfolder just anywhere in the path.

Thanks CBroe

The correct rule is

```
RewriteRule ^subfolder/([A-Za-z0-9\-\.]+) /subfolder.cfm?slug=$1 [QSA]
```